# OnItemClickListener trouble - Not Detect Name of ListView Item

Tags: android, listview

Eclipse Error on **getListAdapter()**: The method getListAdapter(ArrayAdapter) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object o = this.getListAdapter(lvAdapter).getItem(pos);
        String keyword = o.toString();
        makeToast("List Selected: " + pos,"#ff1111","#cfcfcf","testImage");
        Log.d("ListView", String.valueOf(pos));
    }});
```

All another - working normal

Comment: Are you using `ListActivity`?

Comment: try `adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos);`

Comment: just use getListAdapter no requirement of this.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` there is the `OnItemClickListener` you're in. If you remove the `this` it should work. Alternatively, you can use `MyActivity.this.getListAdapter(lvAdapter)` where you replace `MyActivity` with your Activity/Fragment name

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this, change `YouaActivity` with your activity name

```
 listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Object o = YouaActivity.this.getListAdapter(lvAdapter).getItem(pos);
    String keyword = o.toString();
    makeToast("List Selected: " + pos,"#ff1111","#cfcfcf","testImage");
    Log.d("ListView", String.valueOf(pos));
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object o = MyActivity.getListAdapter(lvAdapter).getItem(pos);
        String keyword = o.toString();
        makeToast("List Selected: " + pos,"#ff1111","#cfcfcf","testImage");
        Log.d("ListView", String.valueOf(pos));
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friends :-)))

Normal working this variant:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {
String itemName = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos);
makeToast("List Selected: " + pos + " / " + itemName,"#ff1111","#cfcfcf","testImage");
Log.d("ListView", String.valueOf(pos));
}});
```